# How to convert string 'date' to date time format in python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I've to find days difference. I've string object of date in this format '7/15/2019'. I want to convert it into date time object.

```
date = '7/15/2019'
start_time = datetime.strptime(date, '%b %d %Y')
```

```
ValueError: time data '7/15/2019' does not match format '%b %d %Y'
```

Comment: `start_time = datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y')`?

Answer (score 1):

```
`import datetime
date = '7/15/2019'
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').date()`
```